# Are there any alternative services for virusTotal intelliegent search, to search an app by its SHA256?

Tags: android, hash, md5, sha1, sha256

I am trying to find an alternative to virus-total's intelligence search (that takes SHA1 or SHA256 or md5) and gives the app information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Apart from VirusTotal, there are a few services that give us files from SHA1/SHA256/MD5 hash values.
I have noted them in the following--

1. Meta Defender
2. Jotti
3. Hybrid-Analysis
4. VirusBay
5. ReversingLabs

Among these I found ReversingLabs is one of the most efficient, but a costly service.